# If statement printing all conditions

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a password strength checker function.

```
def passwordStrengthCheck():
  password = "Passw0rd!"
  lower = any(letter.islower() for letter in password)
  upper = any(letter.isupper() for letter in password)
  num = any(char.isdigit() for char in password)
   
  if len(password) < 8:
      print("Password does not meet requirements.")
  elif not lower:
      print("Password does not meet requirements.")
  elif not upper:
      print("Password does not meet requirements.")
  elif not num:
      print("Password does not meet requirements.")
  else:
      for char in password:
          if not (char.isalpha() or char.isdigit() or char == ' '):
              print("Password is accepted.")
          else:
            print("Password does not meet requirements.") 

passwordStrengthCheck()
```

The output I am getting is this

```
Password does not meet requirements.
Password does not meet requirements.
Password does not meet requirements.
Password does not meet requirements.
Password does not meet requirements.
Password does not meet requirements.
Password does not meet requirements.
Password does not meet requirements.
Password is accepted.
```

I can't figure out why I am getting every option plus some extra as an output. I was hoping to get an output that the password either does or doesn't meet requirements.

Comment: It'll help if you make the error messages different so you can tell which ones are being triggered.

Comment: Try printing `char` inside the loop so you can see which character it's checking each iteration. That should also help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking only one character each time and printing a result based on that, check ALL the characters before deciding if the password meets the requirements.

Here, you should check if any character in the string is not alphanumeric or a space, in which case the password is accepted. In other words, if all of the characters are alphanumeric or spaces, then the password does not meet the requirements.

```py
# other checks...
elif all(char.isalpha() or char.isdigit() or char == ' ' for char in password):
  print("Password does not meet requirements.")
else:
  print("Password is accepted")
```

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZLBbsIwDIbvPIXXy9oLmrTLNNHTXgCJJ4gal0RLneC4Qjx9l5R2IGA70ES5/Pb3y/6VcBLj6X0YNLYQVIxHz3onjLQX82Ww@S5ntfpcATh/RIYaFJ1KhyLIaxtHsayg9QxnESz9ulUJ60O4x0bxX4z6boIaozKi7d7KhGTpFoD0bJvc6DI2bOAjj55PYEtSFtupBtpjBPICHaIA46G3jB2SxHWR/dAlt1wfV1zsMm682CWlsshDOTfnqVwwKuU5xXmV8BxwXcNrug8Df36KiH@xNoJqGgyCOvWuHn/Jc/sb65eiGoYf)